# Redis timeseries golang sampling

Tags: database, go, redis, time-series, stock

```
func Red() {
    keyname := "t"
    var client = rt.NewClient("127.0.0.1:6379", "nohelp", nil)
    client.CreateKeyWithOptions(keyname, rt.DefaultCreateOptions)
    client.CreateKeyWithOptions("td", rt.DefaultCreateOptions)
    client.CreateRule(keyname, rt.MaxAggregation, 5000, "td")
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        timestamp := time.Now()
        fmt.Println(time.Now().Unix(), timestamp.String())
        value := float64(i)
        client.Add(keyname, timestamp.Unix(), value)
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
    fmt.Println(client.RangeWithOptions(keyname, rt.TimeRangeMinimum, rt.TimeRangeMaximum, rt.DefaultRangeOptions))
    fmt.Println(client.RangeWithOptions("td", rt.TimeRangeMinimum, rt.TimeRangeMaximum, rt.DefaultRangeOptions))
}
```

This small golang code that I wrote in order to understand redis timeseries sampling/compaction. I tried many many source, I still am failing to understand why my output destination series is empty

```
O/P:
[{1677776687 0} {1677776688 1} {1677776689 2} {1677776690 3} {1677776691 4} {1677776692 5} {1677776693 6} {1677776694 7} {1677776695 8} {1677776696 9}] <nil>
[] <nil>
```

I was expecting value 4 and 9 as output.
I tried with retention period but still same.

now I tried with auto timestamp `client.AddAutoTs(keyname, value)`

in this case I am getting random result such as 2 and 7 or sometime just 4
For Eg:

```
[{1677777452390 0} {1677777453407 1} {1677777454422 2} {1677777455436 3} {1677777456468 4} {1677777457477 5} {1677777458490 6} {1677777459505 7} {1677777460518 8} {1677777461569 9}] <nil>
[{1677777450000 2} {1677777455000 7}] <nil>
```

Can someone plese help here to understand what and why it's happening and How Do I achieve desired result ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Please note that the timestamp is in **milliseconds**.

So `client.Add(keyname, timestamp.Unix(), value)` should be replaced with `client.Add(keyname, timestamp.UnixMilli(), value)`.

Here is the updated demo:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    rt "github.com/RedisTimeSeries/redistimeseries-go"
)

func main() {
    keyname := "t"
    var client = rt.NewClient("127.0.0.1:6379", "nohelp", nil)
    client.CreateKeyWithOptions(keyname, rt.DefaultCreateOptions)
    client.CreateKeyWithOptions("td", rt.DefaultCreateOptions)
    client.CreateRule(keyname, rt.MaxAggregation, 5000, "td")
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        timestamp := time.Now()
        fmt.Println(time.Now().UnixMilli(), timestamp.String())
        value := float64(i)
        client.Add(keyname, timestamp.UnixMilli(), value)
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
    fmt.Println(client.RangeWithOptions(keyname, rt.TimeRangeMinimum, rt.TimeRangeMaximum, rt.DefaultRangeOptions))
    fmt.Println(client.RangeWithOptions("td", rt.TimeRangeMinimum, rt.TimeRangeMaximum, rt.DefaultRangeOptions))
}
```

> I was expecting value 4 and 9 as output.

It does not work as what you expected. It depends on the sampling period.

For this output:

```
[{1677824975163 0} {1677824976163 1} {1677824977164 2} {1677824978166 3} {1677824979167 4} {1677824980169 5} {1677824981170 6} {1677824982173 7} {1677824983174 8} {1677824984176 9}] <nil>
[{1677824975000 4}] <nil>
```

The sampling periods are:

- `1677824975000` ~ `1677824980000`: The max value is `4` (from `1677824979167`)
- `1677824980000` ~ `1677824985000`: The period is not ended when we read from the db, so the data is not generated yet.

For this output:

```
[{1677824999116 0} {1677825000117 1} {1677825001119 2} {1677825002121 3} {1677825003121 4} {1677825004123 5} {1677825005125 6} {1677825006126 7} {1677825007128 8} {1677825008129 9}] <nil>
[{1677824995000 0} {1677825000000 5}] <nil>
```

The sampling periods are:

- `1677824995000` ~ `1677825000000`: The max value is `0` (from `1677824999116`)
- `1677825000000` ~ `1677825005000`: The max value is `5` (from `1677825004123`)
- `1677825005000` ~ `1677825010000`:  The period is not ended when we read from the db, so the data is not generated yet.